Elfinder prevent file download when click open command
I am using Elfinder as web file manager. In elfinder when we click open command on the file like video, its automatically download the file. How to prevent file download when we click open command?
I have already tried using handler like this but its not work
handlers: {
            open: function (event, elfinderInstance) {
                var file = event.data.file;
                var fileUrl = elfinderInstance.url(file.hash);

                event.preventDefault();

                alert('Opening file: ' + file.name + ' is disabled.');
            }
        },

